# Не полностью переведено письмо о закрытии вопроса как дубликат

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты, почта

Только что я внезапно получил на свой e-mail с Меты письмо о закрытии вопроса как дубликат (я даже не знал, что такие бывают), а там не всё переведено.

Imgur лежит, поэтому скриншота не будет, просто скопирую текст:

> Subject: Your question has been closed
>
> [...]
>
> <kbd>Review similar questions</kbd>
>
> Что мне следует делать дальше?
>
> - **Review similar questions**. Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Do any of these answer your
>   question?
> - **Select the suggestions that answer your question.** Your question will be associated with these links so future visitors can easily find the
>   answer. Your question will be marked as a duplicate and become visible
>   to the public again.
>
> ---
>
> What if these suggestions don’t answer my question?
>
> - **Confirm that none of the suggestions answer your question.** Your question will remain hidden for now.
> - **Edit your question.** Add more details about how the question is different from the suggestions.
> - **Submit your edits.** Edits will be reviewed by trusted community members. If approved, the question will become visible to the public.
>
> Спасибо за ваш вклад. Мы рады, что вы здесь.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>You're receiving this message because your Stack Overflow на русском Meta activity triggered this tip or reminder.</sup>

Comment: (Traducir какой-то неудобный, лучше бы какой-нибудь Weblate выкатили...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14616
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14599
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14602
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14595
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14605
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14610
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14566
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14549
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1810
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2842

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.6.9.39464

Comment: Кажется есть, только по частям: [раз](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2394), [два](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1810), [три](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2842)

Comment: [Эта строка вроде как из кнопки](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14599), думаю, вместо «Проверьте» лучше «Проверить»

Comment: @andreymal добавил/исправил.