# Частичный перевод письма о закрытии вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты, почта

Я получил письмо о закрытии моего вопроса на Мете как дубликата, и оно частично на английском:

[image: english-email]

PS: я видел, что об этом уже [писали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11569/), но @αλεχολυτ сказал там, что перевёл, а сейчас, похоже, опять нет переводов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводов:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18340
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18221
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18222
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18223
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18101

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.3.14.43317

Comment: По множественным формам не очень понятно. [Уточняю.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387569/339911)